# PHP stream_socket_client not working in chrooted environment

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, chroot, stream-socket-client

I try to use stream_socket_client() to open a ssh connection, but getting:

```
Could not open socket: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
2018-06-22T13:07:35+02:00 EMERG (0): #0 [internal function]: Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol->Zend\Mail\Protocol\{closure}(2, 'stream_socket_c...', '/httpdocs/vendo...', 213, Array)
#1 /httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php(213): stream_socket_client('ssl://lotsearch...', 0, '', 30)
#2 /httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/Smtp.php(185): Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol->_connect('ssl://lotsearch...')
#3 /httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(397): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp->connect()
#4 /httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(383): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->connect()
#5 /httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(394): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->lazyLoadConnection()
#6 /httpdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(251): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->connect()
```

I am executing this command in an chrooted environment. If I use "normal" bash as shell, everything works fine.
At first I thought that the chrooted-user needs access to `openssh` binary.
But even with access to it, it does not work.

`wget https://google.com` does not work also by the way.

Any thoughts how to get the ssl certificate verifying working in a chrooted environment?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out:

You need to make the following available in the chrooted environment:

```
/usr/bin/openssl
/usr/lib/ssl
/etc/ssl
/usr/share/ca-certificates
```

Then PHP's `stream_socket_client()` function is able to SSL verify certificates. Wget is now also working for SSL-secured websites `wget https://google.com`.

Comment: As just hit an SSL problem on my own, I'd like to add that I was missing /usr/local/share/ca-certificates for our own CAs we deployed on the machines!

Comment: Can you please make the answer more specific - by 'availble' do you mean readable? Writable? Belong to user group? Sorry if this is a little off-track, I don't really know about chroot

Comment: @ScottAnderson They need to be readable, and it has to be able to execute the program. There's unlikely to be any need for them to be writable, unless it's meant to update the certificates or configuration as well.

Comment: In addition, /etc/services may be necessary, else it can't transform e.g. https to 443.